# Fastlane fails to upload dSYM files

Tags: ios, crashlytics, fastlane, dsym

I have set up FastLane to build an app, upload to test flight, and upload dSYM files to Crashlytics. So, I can understand crashes. But, unfortunately on Crashlytics I always get a missing dSYM message.

> This app has xx unprocessed crashes. Upload xx dSYM files to porocess
> them.

```
lane :buildTF do
    desc "Builds and uploads a version to TestFlight with what to test message"
    #cocoapods
    build_app(workspace: "NameOfProject.xcworkspace", scheme: "NameOfProjectScheme")
    upload_to_testflight(changelog: "Fix for the bug")
    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics
  end
```

Am I using it right?

Also, I have tried uploading dSYM files by using the script provided by `FirebaseCrashlytics`. It is located in the project folder `/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols`. I often get Segmentation fault: 11 Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I am also facing the same `segmentation fault  ./upload-symbols -gsp  -p ios` error